# Cmake gives me an error (pthread_create not found) while building BornAgain

Tags: linux, cmake, fedora

I am trying to build the BornAgain software on my computer running the latest version of Fedora 32. I managed to do it before, but I do not even know where to start with the error that I'm getting. In my Terminal I get the following error:

```
> [sjoerd@dhcp-10-240-34-181 ~]$ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/sjoerd/.BornAgain /home/sjoerd/BornAgain/BornAgain  
[sudo] lösenord för sjoerd:   
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1  
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1  
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc  
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - works  
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info  
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done  
-- Detecting C compile features  
-- Detecting C compile features - done  
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++  
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - works  
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info  
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done  
-- Detecting CXX compile features  
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done  
-- Looking for pthread.h  
-- Looking for pthread.h - found  
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD  
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed  
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads  
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found  
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread  
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found  
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found FFTW3: /usr/lib64/libfftw3.so  
-- Found FFTW3: includes at /usr/include, libraries at /usr/lib64/libfftw3.so  
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.6.3")   
-- Found GSL: /usr/include (found version "2.6")   
-- GSL found=TRUE libs=/usr/lib64/libgsl.so;/usr/lib64/libgslcblas.so inc=/usr/include version={GSL_VERSION}  
-- Found Eigen3: /usr/include/eigen3 (Required is at least version "3.3")   
-- Eigen3 include_dir=/usr/include/eigen3 version=3.3.7  
-- Could NOT find Cerf (missing: Cerf_LIBRARIES Cerf_INCLUDE_DIR)   
-- Search cerf in Cerf_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND  
> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.  
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Cerf_LIBRARIES  
    linked by target "cmTC_6517d" in directory /home/sjoerd/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp  
> 
> CMake Error at cmake/extensions/AssertLibraryFunction.cmake:86 (try_compile):  
  Failed to generate test project build system.  
Call Stack (most recent call first):  
  cmake/extensions/FindCerf.cmake:33 (assert_library_function)  
  cmake/modules/SearchInstalledSoftware.cmake:21 (find_package)  
  CMakeLists.txt:64 (include)  
> 
> 
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!  
See also "/home/sjoerd/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".  
See also "/home/sjoerd/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".  
[sjoerd@dhcp-10-240-34-181 ~]$
```

I have been trying to follow the instructions on their webpage:
https://www.bornagainproject.org/documentation/getting-started/installation/linux-detailed/third-party/
https://www.bornagainproject.org/documentation/getting-started/installation/linux-detailed/build-and-install/

And my biggest issue is that they have their instructions for Ubuntu, OpenSUSE och RedHat/CentOS. I think the culprit lies with their instructions to install devtoolset (tried to follow RedHat instructions), which does not seem to exist in the Fedora repos. I tried to install basically anything that's related and tried all packages they named for each distro, but I cannot get beyond the error which I typed above.

Comment: Look a little further pthread_create is NOT the problem `Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found` The actual problem is that it cannot find `Cerf` libraries.

Comment: FYI, really shouldn't use `sudo` to run `cmake` as you've shown above.  Save `root` privileges for only when they are needed.